# Почему не срабатывает метод find() в библиотеке PHP Query? Не выбирает содержимое по классам CSS

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

уважаемые специалисты!

Почему не срабатывает вот такой код:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

    $html = file_get_contents("https://yandex.ru/");

$g = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

$h = $g->find(".teaser__nowrap");
 
var_dump($h);    

?>
```

Если "вардампом" вывести $g, то будет перечисление всего содержимого страницы в виде объектов PHP Query, но метод find() в этих объектах ничего не находит. В то же время, если преобразовать объекты в html методом html(), то, опять-таки, код не отрабатывает, консоль выдает: "call to unidentified function". Голову сломал, не понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: А в выводе `var_dump($g)` искомый класс упоминается?

Comment: Нет, там вообще нет html, выдача является массивом значений и написано вначале: phpQueryObject. Но если переводишь phpQueryObject в html с помощью метода html(), то появляется ошибка "Call to unidentified function.. on string", да и в интернете пишут, что find() является специальным методом для работы с объектами phpQuery